# Magento 2: "The product that was requested doesn't exist. Verify the product and try again."

Tags: magento2

Help me!
I create an API to get product information with ID: getProductByID ($ id). When I run in POSTMAN and the URL: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/magento/rest/V1/products/9" then I get the error result: "The product that was requested doesn't exist. Verify the product and try again. "

I checked in Catalog> Products, the product has an id of 9. Why does the API for this product result do not exist? How to fix this error?

Comment: Surely a bit too late : with this simple URL syntax, I get products with API using SKU, not ID : `.../rest/V1/products/**my_sku**`. After, if I want to get the ID, I get it in the json response : `res['id']`. If you want to get the product directly with ID, you must use **criterias** as explained [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/167075/magento-2-get-product-through-api-using-id) (not tested)

Answer (score 1):

I met the same error with you.
Please try this.

```php
    try{
          $this->productRepository->deleteById($sku);
    }catch (Exception $e){
          echo ""No Exist Product<br/>";
    }
```

I hope it would be helpful.